# Regular expression to match specific words + content inside brackets

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I'm creating a post system, where I will tag external images, Flash, SL etc. with [image:http://anything/anyimage.jpg] or [silverlight:http://anothersite/ilovesilverlight.xap] etc. I'll be rendering the object tags for HTML upon finding the links. I'm stuck with regex, I am quite new to regex so please be constructive while replying, what is wrong with this:

```
        if (text.Contains("[flash:"))
        {
            rgx = new Regex(@"\[flash:(.^\])\]");
            text = rgx.Replace(text, (m =>
            {
                string val = m.Groups[1].Value;
                FlashRenderer ir = new FlashRenderer(val);
                return ir.Render();
            }));
        }
```

Forget about the `FlashRenderer` and what it returns, my problem is with matching.
I get into the if block, but cannot find any instances that match the regex, although I have. I can have multiple external objects in one post, so what I'm trying to do is to negate the `]` character in the match. If I don't negate `]`, there is no problem if I have only one object and no other `]` characters anywhere, but if I have more `]`'s then everything gets messed up as the first regex matches the last occurance of `]` on the whole post, and returning the rest of the whole post as the supposed "URL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
new Regex(@"\[flash:([^\]]+)\]");
```

```sh
\[flash:          # prefix
  (               # capture group
      [^\]]+      # one or more characters except ]
  )               #
\]                # suffix
```

Comment: yep! it works. just to test my understanding:
inside the normal parantheses, it exactly matches "any text of at least 1 characters that does not include literal `]` " is this exaplanation right, just to see if i got it correct or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can use what's called a "non-greedy quantifier", which just means that it eats as few characters as it can while still matching, while the default (greedy) quantifiers eat as many characters as they can while still matching. You make a quantifier (like `*` or `+`) non-greedy by putting a `?` after it:

```
new Regex(@"\[flash:(.+?)\]");
```

Comment: the other answer works as well, so what is the technical difference between the answers? what do they do differently exactly?

Comment: @can: In this case, they work the same but my solution is a bit shorter and (in my opinion) easier to read. In other cases a solution like dtb's won't work. For example, you probably can't match an XML comment without non-greedy quantifiers (`<!--(.*?)-->`).

Comment: XML comments cannot contain `--`, so you'd actually need something like `<!--[^-]*([-][^-]+)*-->`.

Comment: @dtb: Perhaps I should have said "quirks-mode HTML comments"?